# Why is dot notation invalid for a function variable input parameter Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, declaration

I have found that this syntax is valid for defining a function

```
    let path = finalObjs.vendorPath
    const getAllIndexes = (dependenciesResultToHydrateFlat, path) => {

    }
```

However, this syntax is invalid

```
    const getAllIndexes = (dependenciesResultToHydrateFlat, finalObjs.vendorPath) => {

    }
```

**Why is it not allowed to use dot notation directly to reference a property value when defining a function? It feels like these two are functionally the same and I don't understand why the latter is invalid. Explanation from the wizards is appreciated.**

Comment: Those are parameter names, not expressions.  That doesn't actually make any sense.

Comment: And `let path` in your first example doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Path is equal to the vendorPath field on the finalObjs object

Comment: Are you aware that the two instances of `path` in your first example are _completely different_ entities that just happen to have the same name? Or is that part of your question?

Comment: Fwoop, duh. makes sense

Comment: No worries, it's a common mistake.

Comment: as a side note: you can use destructuring to achieve this. `const getAllIndexes = (dependenciesResultToHydrateFlat, { vendorPath: path }) => {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I know this might neglect but it could be helpful)

You also can set default values for your function parameters.

Code:

```js
const getAllIndexes = (dependenciesResultToHydrateFlat, path=finalObjs.vendorPath) => {

}
```

With this, you can change the path afterwards by giving it a value. Otherwise it would use the 'default' value you set to the specific parameter.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you kindly

Comment: @Goldfish Thank you! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Parameters can be named anything, a given parameter is the name that will be assumed for that argument at the time of the function call